# Suitability of the glmnet defaults (R)

Tags: r, glmnet

Recently I came across the claim that one should never rely on the "default" lambda sequence from the glmnet package, and it's always best to supply your own one:

```
cv.glmnet(..., lambda=10^(seq(m,-n,0.2)))
```

However, I can't figure out why this is so, as I have not encountered any evidence to support that claim.

Does anybody know of an academic  reference that discusses this in detail? Thanks!

Comment: I found some of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686067/default-lambda-sequence-in-glmnet-for-cross-validation) to be relevant (maybe even answer some of your question).

Comment: In particular it seems that the consensus is that choosing a default lambda sequence can be difficult and a user should fit the model and then plot the deviance/log(lambda) curve to see if the chosen lambda actually minimizes the cross validation error or if the supplied lambda sequence needs to be extended on one end.

Comment: So its not that the default is bad and there should be some other default, but rather that any default may not be ideal and results may need to be inspected on a case by case basis, i.e. the sequence you supplied in your original post might also not be good.

Comment: although I think the default lambda sequence is fine, there is a bug that sometimes makes the glmnet crash when creating the lambda sequence and it can be avoided by providing your own. It is very rare, but if like me, you are doing simulations of permutation tests, you will encounter it.

Answer (score 6):

Elaborating on my comments:

The default may or may not be alright, depending on your data. You should plot the average cross validation error against the (log)lambda sequence. If the minimum occurs at a boundary then you may want to expand the bounds of the lambda sequence appropriately to see if a more appropriate lambda may be found outside of the range that was tested.

However, if the default lambda sequence is such that the lowest lambda results in all variables being included and the highest lambda results in no variables being included, then you can't really improve on that sequence (other than making it a finer grid).